# Detecting a message box opened in another application

Tags: vb.net, process

I am developing a windows service, in VB.NET, that launches a legacy application that performs some work.  The service acts as a wrapper around the legacy app allowing users to automate an otherwise manual operation.

Everything is working great, except occasionally the legacy app displays a messagebox.  When it does this the process halts until the message box is closed.

As the service will be running on a server there will be no user to close the message box.

The service launches the legacy application in a `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Is there way to detect that a message box has been displayed by a process that I have started using `System.Diagnostics.Process`? And is there a way to close the messagebox through code?

Answer (score 2):

I also found that EnumChildWindows does not return the MessageBox. But I found a site that showed me how to do it. http://vbcity.com/forums/t/105842.aspx
You want to call GetWindow passing in GW_ENABLEDPOPUP. It worked like a charm. Thanks to Scott Waletzko!

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindWindow` to find the app, the use `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate all it's childwindows until you find the messagebox (if the messagebox isn't a direct child of the main window of the app you might have to have recursive calls I think).

You might be able to skip the `FindWindow` call and instead use the `MainWindowHandle` property of the `Process`, but I haven't checked if that works.

A good tool for looking at all this is Spy++ which can help you see some information you can get hold of about a running process.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I was unable to get your solution to work.  EnumChildWindows only returned the main window not the message box.

I am currently working on solution by hooking into windows messages based on this article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WindowInterceptor.aspx?fid=1070466&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2624936